# How to make html created by javascript SEOable ? how react.js do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo

my page is created by appendchild and innerHTML by javascript,how to make it good for SEO?

how react.js do that?

Comment: `React` app is not `SEO-friendly`

Comment: but I saw some website created by react that google can scratch the content of the website,will pages  created by plain appendchild and innerHTML also can be scratch by google?

Comment: [__How do you use React.js for SEO?__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252768/how-do-you-use-react-js-for-seo)

Comment: thanks,good article.But do you know if I host my website on github,is there some article for not your own server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your site is just fine for SEO as it is.

Edit: Google has a tool that shows you exactly how their bot sees your site: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468

Oh but first, let's define a really narrow definition of SEO as "when Google crawls my page, it will see the same text that the humans see when they view my page".

Google has been executing JavaScript when indexing for years. [Officially two years ago](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), a [confirmation of sorts a year ago](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).

I have no idea if Bing makes an attempt to run JS. Probably.

So when people say React is good for SEO, they probably either don't know that Googlebot runs JavaScript, or they're talking about Google's performance penalty for slow sites, which is valid.

That for me is one of the best reasons to use React with server-side rendering. Your site will load a *lot* faster because it doesn't need any JavaScript to load before the humans can start reading. This is good for SEO.

(Having said all that, high quality content is the *real* SEO juice.)

Comment: If I don't do server side rendering will google crawls my page?

Is this means google will excute any javascript on my site before crawls on it?    thanks for reply.

Comment: Yes. You can see your site using this tool: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468

Comment: Thanks,but why do react still need to server side rendering for SEO?

Comment: React *does not need server side rendering for SEO*. Anyone that says so is wrong. There is a lot of misunderstanding about SEO (probably the reason this answer is -1 points). Here's someone that actually tested if Google will index a React site that is only client-side rendered: http://chrisarasin.com/react-seo/

Comment: Thanks for the answer